# Appfabric remove host from cluster

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, appfabric

I have AppFabric installed on my primary box - its working as expected. I tried joining another server to the cluster - for whatever reason its giving me lots of trouble. I don't really need it as part of the cluster - was more just trying to add it from a curiosity standpoint. So I now find myself wanting to remove it from the cluster - but can't find a powershell command that would allow me to do so - any advice?

Not all commands listed here appear to work:
http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2010/04/03/powershell-and-windows-server-appfabric/

ex. Unregister-CacheHost, Remove-CacheHost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the Powershell configuration that you're trying to run those commands in? Have you got the AppFabric configuration commands loaded?

There are two sets of Powershell commands installed when you install AppFabric, a set for administration (New-Cache, Remove-Cache etc) and a set for configuration (Unregister-CacheHost, Remove-CacheHost). If you haven't got the configuration commands loaded in Powershell, you'll need to run this line (or include it in your Powershell profile).

```
import-module distributedcacheconfiguration
```

You should then have access to the configuration cmdlets.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I wasn't aware of the distinction. If others stumble upon this you actually need to use import-module distributedcacheconfiguration (instead of add-module). Cheers for the answer.

Comment: @user67545 I only discovered this myself yesterday when I was researching this answer! I've updated the answer to use `import-module`.